Add custom text in native call notification in react native callkeep
React native call keep shows the native notification when receiving a call it has the name of the caller and some text like Incoming call via. Is there any way where we can customise the text. I just want to add the app name at the last, like: Incoming call via myapp.
I don't see any relevant explicit code in react native callkeep where we can update the content, though we can use the selfManaged option to add custom UI (though the docs are not clear about it), but i just want to small change. Is there any workaround for this?
